# PayPal Rest API suddenly got Instrument_Declined error

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

`"{\"name\":\"INSTRUMENT_DECLINED\",\"message\":\"The instrument presented  was either declined by the processor or bank, or it can't be used for this payment.\",\"information_link\":\"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors\",\"debug_id\":\"21fe4e5f2f8b3\"}"` PayPal blog https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/says It is a issue with funding source but It was working fine with all the funding source before

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a problem with the funding source. It's been declined.

There is no technical issue here.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an explanation and solution in the official paypal documentation.

> A buyer's funding source can fail for several reasons, including:
>
> The billing address associated with the financial instrument could not
> be confirmed. The transaction exceeds the card limit. The card issuer
> denied the transaction. If a funding source fails, the Orders API
> returns the INSTRUMENT_DECLINED error. Handle this error and provide
> the buyer an opportunity to select a different payment option by
> restarting the payment in the onApprove function.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/checkout/add-capabilities/handle-funding-failures/